# OWIN + OAuth - How to provide User ID instead of UserName

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oauth, owin

I'm creating my own authorization provider that extends from `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`.

```
public class AsyncAuthorizationProvider : OAuthAuthorizationProvider {
     //...
     public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context) {
         string username = context.UserName; //Returns the username sent in the request.
         string password = context.Password; //Returns the password sent in the request.
         //...
     }
}
```

As you can see `OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext`'s context already comes with two useful properties for retrieving the username and password.

This information is sent by the user when requested to my oauth endpoint:

```
{
    "grant_type": "password",
    "client_id": "someClientId",
    "client_secret": "someClientSecret",
    "username": "myUsername",
    "password": "myPassword"
}
```

This JSON is stored in the OAuth context, but what if I want to send my `userId` instead of my `username`?. What if my application allows for duplicate usernames and I want to use the `id` to uniquely identify one?

Of course, I can send my Id as `"username": "myUserId"`. But this doesn't seem right.

`username` should contain an `username`. This may confuse consumers.

Is there a way to send an `userId` **and** to retrieve it from the context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set any parameter you would like to and get it as the below:

```
var formCollection = (Microsoft.Owin.FormCollection)context.Parameters;

var userId = formCollection.Get("userId");
```